# python pip install could not build wheels, needs c++ build tools

Tags: python, docker, pip, conda

I'm trying to set up some python dependencies for a dockerfile. I am completely new to docker, so probably will struggle to understand unless it is dumbed down a bit for me. To get my dependencies, I made a temporary virtual environment so that I could `pip freeze` the list of installed packages and use that for my docker setup. I then tried to `pip install` one of the specific packages, but it fails with a big red error message and requires build tools:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

The package is easily downloaded with the `conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan`. But I imagine that installing conda into the docker image (if that's even possible) would be some hassle, especially for a single package, and at any rate it seems overly complicated for me since I am not too familiar with docker. What are my options?

Comment: If you try to `pip install` in the Docker image (which will most likely be Linux), you can install the compiler and it should work out. You won't need Visual C++, which is Windows only.